# Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to run a powershell -Command to execute a powershell file as a post build event in Visual studio 2013
But i am getting

> 'Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,  operable program or batch file

error on output window and

```
Powershell -Command exited with code 9009 error
```

Full Error Message:

```
'Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
10>  operable program or batch file.
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4429,5): error MSB3073: The command "echo "C:\dev\tfs\Main\Shared\AggregationComponents\GenerateSchema.cmd"
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4429,5): error MSB3073: call "C:\dev\tfs\Main\Shared\AggregationComponents\GenerateSchema.cmd"
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4429,5): error MSB3073: echo "Move the PhoenixData namespace schema suffixing it"
10>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4429,5): error MSB3073: Powershell -Command "C:\dev\tfs\Main\Shared\AggregationComponents\MoveAndRenameXsds.ps1 'C:\dev\tfs\Main\Shared\AggregationComponents\bin\Debug\' 'C:\dev\tfs\Main\Shared\AggregationComponents\..\PublishedAnalyticsXsds' '.Aggregation'"" exited with code 9009.
========== Rebuild All: 8 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 skipped ==========
```

Comment: The unmatched quotation marks are suspicious. Are you sure you copied it correctly? Please share the actual command line you are trying to execute. (Also verify that it is on your PATH.)

Comment: @RahulLodha This problem could be due to pathext variable problem. See http://superuser.com/questions/675006/

Comment: An old thread I know, but I had this issue recently using the JetBrains WebStorm CLI (similar to VS Code) and turns out that if I used Windows Command Prompt as Administrator it worked fine.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Sounds like you're missing an environment variable.

Add this to your `Path` environment variable:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

OR

Change your script to this:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "your command"
```

Comment: It worked. i had to restart visual studio after path change. Thank You! :)

Comment: Glad it worked.  Strange that it was missing though.  I've always seen it populated by default.

Comment: What worked for me was C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Comment: I had to move the path %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ from the System environment list box to the User environment list box, as per this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1034020 . Otherwise the %SYSTEMROOT% part was not expanding to actual path.

Comment: This is working and , Have to  restart visual studio after path change. Otherwise will show the same error-  default path- C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\

Answer (score 13):

### You only need to add it to your **environment variables**, just follow the following two simple steps:

### 1.write env in the search bar

**or**
Right click start button -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables... -> Select PATH

### 2. click on the new button and add the following path:

`C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

**or** `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

---

[image: write env in the search bar]

[image: choose path]

[image: click Ok]

Answer (score 4):

Remove BOM byte from the beginning of batch file or convert it's encoding to ANSI. BOM treats system to think you use unavailable command.

Comment: The approved solution did work for me, but this was really the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

My mistake was just that I forgot to run Visual Studio / command prompt as an Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

try

'`%SYSTEMROOT%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe tracert google.com`'

might require `\\` instead of `\`.