# 'Select-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: python, powershell, iis

I want to enable IIS by Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature of powershell.there is a python program having one line code:

```
os.system('powershell.exe Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where { $_.FeatureName -Like "IIS-*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FeatureName)')
```

when I run the python program,it says that 
'Select-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

I search for many ways.But no one can solve this problem,can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine the `os.system` call is using cmd.exe, which is mangling your arguments before they get to powershell.exe. Everything before the pipe is passed to powershell.exe, everything after is passed to cmd.exe programs. There is no `Select-Object` program.

Use Python's [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) instead of `os.system`, per [recommendations in the `system` function's documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system):

> The [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function. See the [Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess-replacements) section in the subprocess documentation for some helpful recipes.

You could also base-64 encode your command and pass that to PowerShell's `-EncodedCommand` property.

```
cmd = base64.b64encode( "Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where { $_.FeatureName -Like "IIS-*"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FeatureName)'"
os.system("powershell.exe -EncodedCommand " + cmd)
```

Comment: thanks, I have done as you said.but it shows another error: <br/>                is not recognized as the
name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException       <br/>   there are some gibberish not shown in the error.

Comment: I also use subprocess module. <per> ps_cmdlet = 'powershell.exe Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | Where-Object { $_.FeatureName -Like \"IIS-*\"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FeatureName)'
    subprocess.call(ps_cmdlet)<code>      but it shows that:<br/> <per>

You must provide a value expression following the '-Like' operator.
+ ... tureName -Like IIS-*} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FeatureName)
Unexpected token 'IIS-*' in expression or statement.
   <code> is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

from [Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778121/powershell-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr)

> Sounds like you're missing an environment variable.

---

from [Command Prompt Error 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24904945/command-prompt-error-c-program-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-c)

> If a directory has spaces in, put quotes around it.

---

from 
https://superuser.com/questions/571715/windows-command-line-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operab and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20071121-00/?p=24433/

> It's possible that you have an 'AutoRun' command set in the registry ... try running `cmd /d` and see if that produces the same
>   message. The `/d` flag means "don't run AutoRun commands", which makes
>   it perfect for testing this.
>
> The registry values are:
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun
> ```
>
> Check both. By default, neither should exist. You may wish to fix the
>   command strings in yours, or even delete them entirely.

Answer (score -2):

If you use `sel` instead of `select` it will work