# MongoDB Compass loading forever

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB Compass won't launch.  It was working an hour ago, but now it just shows this screen forever.

[image]

I've tried rebooting.  And even uninstalling and re-installing Compass.  But every time I launch it, it just shows the loading screen and never proceeds.  If I go to Connect > Connect to..., it just opens another window that does the same thing.

> Version 1.10.9
>
> Windows 10 x64

How can I get this program to launch correctly?  What should I investigate to try to figure this out?

Comment: Installing 1.11.0-beta.1 worked.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Had the same issue today, with the Version 1.10.9 on Mac OSX. I then reinstalled MongoDB Compass Community Edition to the latest Beta version (Version 1.11.0-beta.1), the loading proceeded and everything went fine.

Answer (score 4):

Same here. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling. No joy.

I reinstalled an older version 1.8.2 which worked fine. Must be an issue with the latest release.

Edit: I upgraded to 1.10.9 this morning and reverted to 1.8.2 after coming across this issue.

Comment: was this bug reported upstream? it would be useful to have feedback from the community there. also, when you edit, you do not need to add "edit" - try to have a finalized version of your answer at once...

Comment: "also, when you edit, you do not need to add "edit" - try to have a finalized version of your answer at once..." ok will do thanks

Answer (score 4):

After having the same issue today (november 24:th) i used the latest stable version (1.10.10) and it solved the problem. I´m on Mac OS Sierra (10.12.6).

Answer (score 4):

On window 7, i found the issue was because of two reason and both were related to power shell.

1. First problem was because of execution policy related to power shell script, which can be solved by running the following with administrator privilege.
   Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
2. After this, please check the power shell version, in case you are trying to install latest version of mongodb on window 7, power cell version needs to me minimum of 3.0, in my case it was 2.0 and because of that installation was getting stuck. After upgrading power shell to latest, installation went through quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to surprisingly fix this issue by restarting my computer. I was on Ubuntu 18.04, Compass v1.x (somewhere this year).

I understand that the poster is on Windows but this was the first hit on Google.

Comment: Restarting worked for me as well.  Mac osx.  It is surprising how well the "turn it off and back on again" trick works.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be forever error, even in 3.6.3 version, that i've tried today. There are questions about the error everywhere.
The link below

[Installation/Update of MongoDB 3.6.2 on Windows Hangs](https://checkinnuggets.wordpress.com/2018/01/14/installation-update-of-mongodb-3-6-2-on-windows-hangs/)

explains the problem - the install trying to run execute the PowerShell script to download/install MongoDB Compass, which seems to hang due to insufficient rights.
DO NOT install Compass, or install it later with appropriate rights.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem here.
My MongoDB version v4.2.1, compass-1.23 on Win 10 OS.

In MongoDB Compass screen panel, I went to View-> Toggle DevTools.
In Console section there was error indication in red :
"""Error: Command failed: powershell (...'powershell' is not recognized as an internal ..."""

Powershell can be added to environment variables paths:
Please check this:
[Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778121/powershell-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr)

So, I closed MongoDB Compass window. Then I added path to environment variables:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

And it solved my problem.

You can also add this line too, to enable MongoDB cmd line commands (your location and version can be different):

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin\
```

Please check this: [How to Install MongoDB on Windows 7/8/10 | How to Install Mongo Compass as separate installer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgZrTK595kM)