# How to start mongoDB Compass on windows?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

i can't start mongoDB compass...

```
Error: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
'powershell' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme ex�cutable ou un fichier de commandes.


    at makeError (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:39:19)
    at osName (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
    at Object.default (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-js-metrics\lib\resources\app.js:31:16)
    at result (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-js-metrics\node_modules\lodash\result.js:51:40)
    at child.getAttributes (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-js-metrics\node_modules\ampersand-state\ampersand-state.js:430:55)
    at child.serialize (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-js-metrics\node_modules\ampersand-state\ampersand-state.js:104:24)
    at child.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\mongodb-js-metrics\lib\resources\base.js:28:26)
    at arrayEach (C:\Program Files\MongoDB Compass\resources\app.asar\node_modules\ampersand-collection-lodash-mixin\node_modules\lodash\_arrayEach.js:15:9)
```

[image: 1]

I don't know what to do...
If someone could help me please

Comment: Check this documents [Download and Install Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/install/). If you have already installed, just double-click the Compass executable (`MongoDBCompass.exe`) in the install folder. Also, include the Windows and Compass versions in your post.

Comment: I'm on windows PRO Version 10.0.18363
 and the version of compass :mongodb-compass-1.22.1-win32-x64

Comment: Did you try to run by double-clicking the Compass executable?

Comment: yes it shows the same error

Comment: You can _try_ re-installing (remove the present installation) and install again. Try downloading the ZIP archive, unzip and use it.

Comment: try that right now thanks

Comment: i got the same error :(

Comment: I have 1.21 version running on my Windows 64bit. You can try that version. Do you have MongoDB installed and running?

Comment: See this post which has similar error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778121/powershell-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr

Comment: i install the 1.20 and it works but not with the 1.21