# Making python as windows service

Tags: python, powershell, nssm

I have created python file which intern call PowerShell Script. I want to make this as windows service. can anyone of you help me with that.  I'm trying by using NSSM. when I started running service, getting error as "PowerShell is not recognized as internal or external Windows command"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [PyInstaller](https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/) for create python as a service

Once you install it using

```
pip install PyInstaller
```

then you can create exe file using

```
pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=win32timezone App.py
```

After that you can start it as a sevice

```
dist\App.exe install
dist\App.exe start
```

Check bellow for "PowerShell is not recognized as internal or external Windows command"

[Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778121/powershell-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr)